# split file into chunks using Multithreaded in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to split file into chunks using multithread, i am trying but, i dont know proper way how to use multithread code because i am new  in multithread. My main goal is to reduce the cpu utilization and complete the splitting of the file quickly.Please help me how to use multithred in my code.
 Thanks in advance.

Some code

```
public class ServerSocketThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    infoPort.setText("I'm waiting here: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                }
            });

          while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            FileTxThread fileTxThread = new FileTxThread(socket);
            fileTxThread.start();
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FileTxThread implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    FileTxThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis;
            ArrayList<byte[]> al = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

            final int cSize = 64 * 1024;
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.mp3");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            int read;

            final double pieces = file.length() / 2048; // used to return file length.
            int fileSize = (int) file.length();
            int readlen = 1024;
            // for (int i = 0; i <= pieces; i++) {
            //        System.out.println("If loop" + i);

            while (fileSize > 0) {
                if (fileSize < 1024) {
                    readlen = fileSize;
                    System.out.println("Hello.........");
                }
                bytes = new byte[readlen];
               read = bis.read(bytes, 0, readlen);
                fileSize -= read;
                al.add(bytes);
            }


            BufferedOutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/new.mp3"));

            for (int ii = 1; ii < al.size(); ii++) {
                out1.write(al.get(ii));
                //  out1.flush();
            }
            out1.close();
           File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "new.mp3");
            System.out.println("File1 length  output " + file1.length());
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Explain your question plz, like what you have? what you want? what is the problem? and what have you tried?

Comment: Hi sir,I am trying to split file and with using multithreading  and then writing file in a single file . because i want save time to transfer file.

Comment: Could you be more specific how you are trying to split your file using threads ?